# air: maximising window on startup

Tags: apache-flex, air

In my air app I am maximizing the app window on creation complete event. Because of this I initially get a smaller window for a few milliseconds which is maximized after all UI elements are rendered. Is there any way I can specify that the initial size of the window should be maximal? Hard coding the size will not works as the screen sizes may change. My current code is:

```
<s:WindowedApplication .... creationComplete="maximize();">
.
.
.
</mx:WindowedApplication>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the initial window not visible (in the app.xml file).  Then in an applicationComplete event handler maximize the window and make it visible.

Comment: It is not optimal as it creates a delay before the window becomes visible. However, no other alternative exists.